# How to implement a Cancel button on a userform?

Tags: vba, outlook

I have a UserForm with a cancel button.

```
Sub DialogTest()
    MyForm.Show
End Sub

Private Sub CancelButton_Click()
    Unload Me
    End
End Sub
```

I also tried `MyForm.Hide`,  `End` by itself,  `cmdExit_Click`.

The cancel button does not close the dialog nor does it cause the debugger to come up.

Comment: yes, it is named CancelButton

Comment: where is the **Unload Me** code located?

Comment: i'm not really sure what you're asking... i provided the exact location of Unload Me  in my code sample above... it's in Private Sub CancelButton_Click()

Comment: By where I meant Sheet, Module, or UserForm. I was only able to Unload the UserForm when the code was pasted **in** the UserForm (Which I accessed by double-clicking on the cancel-button from VBA)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was only able to replicate your issue when the `Unload Me` Sub was pasted in a  Worksheet or Module. When the Sub is in the **Userform**, it works fine.

Here, the code is pasted in a module and does not close the Userform

[image]

*Instead,* from VBE, double click on your UserForm, then double click on your Cancel Button.

Then paste the code here

[image]

Comment: perfect. thanks.  im not sure why that is not made clear on any of the articles i googled all day. makes sense now