# VBA Excel Userforms, Show, Hide

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have a question regarding instances of userforms.

When a userform is constructed via an object in a module (e.g. set frm = new Userform2)  can I hide it and restore it by the show method even when the sub is run until the end?

Let's say:

1. userform creation by sub1
2. entering values to the userform
3. hiding the userform with sub2
4. restore userform with all values by sub3 with the show method

I got really strange behavior when testing code with show and hide methods on module level or Userform Code but what I got finally to work is that using a global variable and the following code in a standard module:

```
Global frm As UserForm2
Option Explicit

Sub sub1()
Set frm = New UserForm2
    With frm
        .Show vbModeless
    End With
End Sub

Sub sub2()
    With frm
        .Hide
    End With
End Sub

Sub sub3()
    With frm
        .Show vbModeless
    End With
End Sub
```

It's often said that global variables should be avoided. Is it even possible here? Do I miss something?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50770939/6706419

Comment: What were the strange results?  I'd code it similar, apart from declaring the variable at the module level like so `Public/Private f As UserForm1` and maybe a sub for the showing part to ensure consistent "showing"  It would be better maybe if the form also checked the existience of `frm` on opening, so if run from F5, and to make sure the sub2 and 3 have an object to operate on.

Comment: Why are you `.Hide`ing at a Module Level, instead of as part of the UserForm?  Also, if you just `UserForm2.Show`, you can show the existing instance, with no need to create a `New UserForm2` at any point

Comment: This is a must read when showing/hiding UserForms: https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/userform1-show/

Comment: thanks Ricardo Diaz for posting the link. I read the article but it's hard for me to understand fully his approach which is more oop oriented. I stored it and will go over several times. But as he wrote unexpected behavior seems to happen sometimes depending how the code is structured

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I really want is to hide the userform but keep the instance with all values set before. Here is my original code and I now realized that I mixed things up and made and error. I had an "end" in a condition and this forces the UF not to show resp. killing all instances.
@Chronocidal:
In fact I hide within code within the UserForm. This is part of a button which transfers set data from UF to sheet. But I think that is not important where to hide or?
Now it is working as I expected. Thanks to all of you

```
Global myfrm As FormFillInformation
Option Explicit

Sub InitUserFormGeneralInformation()
Dim chkfrm As Boolean
chkfrm = CheckFrmIsHidden
If chkfrm = True Then
    myfrm.Show vbModeless
    End '<<<<<========== completely wrong but overseen
Else
    Set myfrm = New FormFillInformation
    myfrm.Show vbModeless

End If

End Sub


Function CheckFrmIsHidden() As Boolean
Dim frm As Object
CheckFrmIsHidden = False
For Each frm In VBA.UserForms
 If frm.Name = "FormFillInformation" Then
    CheckFrmIsHidden = True
 End If
Next
End Function
```